# can we keep the child node expanded even after refreshing the root node? in c#

Tags: c#

In my winforms application, there is a requirement to keep tree view child node active even after root node is re-freshed( clicking enter on root node twice) , is it possible at first place? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Are you talking about some specific *UI Control*? Maybe a tree view? If so, please add that detail. If not, I've not a clue what nodes you're talking about.

Comment: yes ,I have added it now,thanks for correction .

Comment: If  you can kep track of the active node you can EnsureVisible to re-expand it..

Comment: Thanks for the solution .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ExpandAll methode of the treeview control in order to expand all nodes :

```
treeView1.ExpandAll();
```

Or you can expand only the node that you want to expand :

```
 treeView1.Nodes["myNode"].Expand();
 //Or 
 treeView1.Nodes[indexOfYourNode].Expand();
```